# Infinite loop on QTableWidget signal (cellChanged)

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a signal coming from QTableWidget to slot where is the function `recalculate(int, int)`. Based on the user input, the function does some calculations and changes the cell background color.

```
connect(ui->tableWidget_input, SIGNAL(cellChanged(int, int)), this, SLOT(recalculate(int, int)));
```

Problem is the cellChanged emits the signal when the background color is changed, I need the signal emission **only** when the **text is changed**.

The color change causes the infinite loop like this:

1. Users changes the cell value, the signal is emitted.
2. `Recalculate`(): When a condition is passed, the background is changed.
3. When background is changed, Qt thinks the cell was changed and the signal is emitted.
4. `Recalculate`(): When a condition is passed, the background is changed.
5. Again and again into infinity.

Please, do you have any idea how to do signal emission by the **text change only** - no background color change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to block the emission of QTableWidget signals using [blockSignals()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals):

```cpp
void Foo::recalculate(int row, int column){
    ui->tableWidget_input->blockSignals(true);
    // update here
    ui->tableWidget_input->blockSignals(false);   
}
```